# SOAP request returns code 404 after removing namespace from @PayloadRoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-ws

I am getting http code 404 after removing namespace field from @PayloadRoot where it was working when namespace was present there. Documentation says namespace is an optional field but after removing it its behavior is changed.

**With namespace:**

```
@PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE, localPart = "doSomething")
@ResponsePayload
public DoSomethingResponse update(@RequestPayload DoSomething doSomething) {
    return processRequest(doSomething);
}
```

**Without namespace:**

```
@PayloadRoot(localPart = "doSomething")
@ResponsePayload
public DoSomethingResponse update(@RequestPayload DoSomething doSomething) {
    return processRequest(doSomething);
}
```

I am new to this part and do not understand this behavior.

Is it possible to have the @PayloadRoot without namespace here ? as that is the current requirement.

Comment: Yes it is optional but only of there is no namespace in the xsd/wsdl as well. In short it has to match the value from the contract else it will not match incoming requests.